# MySQL Poolconnection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
MysqlDataSource source = new MysqlDataSource();
source.setURL(properties.getString("url"));
source.setUser(properties.getString("user"));
source.setPassword(properties.getString("password"));
```

How do set quantity of min and max connections in pool connection ?
Like here

```
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
dataSource.setUsername("username");
dataSource.setPassword("password");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<database>");
dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
```

Comment: `MysqlDataSource` doesn't provide that kind of setting, and neither does `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` is a simple `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation that only serves as a simple factory for connections, it does not provide connection pooling.

The MySQL Connector/J driver does not provide any data source that provides connection pooling. Judging by the name, you might think `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` is one, but it is only a factory for use by a connection pool, it isn't a connection pool itself.

If you want a connection pool, use a connection pool library like Apache DBCP (which provides that `BasicDataSource` in your second example), HikariCP, or c3p0.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put it in connection string: `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?max-connections=100..."`

Comment: The MySQL Connector/J driver has no such connection property.